# Locking error in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, serial-port

I am trying to do a request-response communication module in c#, using a SerialPort. The 
This is a very simple implementation, just to demonstrate that it kinda-works (SerialPort is not working properly (it is a USB virtual COM port), and sometimes eats a few characters, probably some windows driver bug).

However the demo does not work :-/

When Using a propertygrid on the form, which reads out properties of an object, which in turn sends a request to read a property from the remote device, something very strange happens: More than one simulteneous call to SendCommand is made at once.

I tried using a lock{} block to make the calls sequenctial, but it does not work. Even with the lock, more than one call is enters the protected area.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
    SerialPort sp;

    public byte[] SendCommand(byte[] command)
      {
          //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
          lock (sp)
          {
              Console.Out.WriteLine("ENTER");
              try
              {

                  string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(command);

                  string request = String.Format("{0}{1}\r", target_UID, base64);

                  Console.Out.Write("Sending request... {0}", request);

                  sp.Write(request);

                  string response;

                  do
                  {
                      response = sp.ReadLine();
                  } while (response.Contains("QQ=="));

                  Console.Out.Write("Response is: {0}", response);

                  return Convert.FromBase64String(response.Substring(target_UID.Length));
              }

              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");
                  throw e;
              }
              finally
              {
                  Console.Out.WriteLine("EXIT");
              }
          }

      }
```

The output:

```
ENTER
Sending request... C02UgAABAA=
Response is: cgAABAAARwAAAA==

EXIT
ENTER
Sending request... C02UgQARwA=
ENTER
Sending request... C02UgAABAA=
Response is: gQARwAAPHhtbD48bWVzc2FnZT5IZWxsbyBYWDIhPC9tZXNzYWdlPjxkZXN0aW5haXRvbj5NaXNpPC9kZXN0aW5hdGlvbj48L3htbD4=
```

Notice the two ENTER-s, without an EXIT between them? How is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure it fixes this problem, but it's generally much safer to lock on a private object unrelated to the sp object (e.g. `private object locker;`) to avoid any possible internal uses of locking on (in  this case) the `sp` object.

Comment: Changed that, but the situation does not change. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to keep in mind what the *lock* keyword does, it allows only one **thread** to enter the lock.  Problem is, you are not using any threads.  All of this code runs on the UI thread, the main thread of your program.

The next detail you need to know is that the UI thread is special, it is *re-entrant*.  The `sp.ReadLine();` call is going to block the UI thread.  That is illegal, the UI thread of a GUI program operates as a "single threaded apartment", enabled by the [STAThread] attribute on your program's Main() method.  The contract of an STA thread forbids it from blocking, that's very likely to cause deadlock.

To follow the requirements of an STA, the CLR does something special whenever code that runs on the UI thread performs a blocking operation, like SerialPort.ReadLine() does.  It pumps a message loop to ensure that messages that Windows sends keep getting dispatched.  That message loop does the same thing that Application.Run() does.

Maybe you can see where this is heading, the PropertyGrid is allowed to again call your SendCommand() method.  The lock doesn't work at all, this happens on the same thread.

Solving this problem isn't so easy, we can't see the code that gets SendMessage() triggered.  But you will need to prevent this from happening, somehow.  More background on this behavior in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4540244/17034).

Comment: Actually, the code that invokes SendMessage is the property accessor (getter), that builds up the command body based on which property is accessed, and returns whatever SendMessage returns.

Basically my object is just a front-end to hide how the SendMessage has to be parametrized.

I guess this won't be an easy fix, as you suggested...

Comment: But if what you say is true (that in case of blocking the UI thread the message queue gets pumped), how is it possible to use propertyGrids on objects that need to make network transfers (in our case the SerialPort is the "network") in order to calculate their properties?

Comment: Let's keep this as simple as possible, the underlying problem is complicated enough.  A strong .NET design guide rule is that properties should have very few side-effects.  If a property getter does anything non-trivial then it should be converted to a method instead.  You are violating this rule in spades, there's a ton of code that runs when your property getter is used.  Not just subtle either.  It is very slow, it can throw exceptions, it takes a lock.  A property getter should *never* do any of those things.  Never write code like that, it will get you in trouble.

Comment: "Never write code like that, it will get you in trouble" - Yeah, it just did :)

Comment: @ÁkosVandra:  In case this (excellent) answer is not entirely clear, see this recent question for a more detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983753/under-what-conditions-can-a-thread-enter-a-lock-monitor-region-more-than-once/13985497#13985497

Answer (score 5):

Where is the field `sp` assigned?  Locks only work on non-null objects.

If `sp` is assigned differently on each call, then the lock won't be mutually exclusive (locks are only mutually exclusive on the same object instance).  In that case, you'd need to have a static field to be used for locking:

```
private static readonly object _lockObject = new object();
```

**Edit:**  I see now based on comments in other answers that you are actually running this logic on the UI thread, which is causing the lock to be re-entered multiple times on the same thread (the UI thread) when the message queue is pumped.  Run this code on a different thread, and you will gain two advantages:  (1) the UI will not lock up as this potentially long-running code executes, and (2) the lock will always be acquired on a new thread, ensuring that subsequent calls to `SendCommand` will all be on their own thread, and thus enter the lock sequentially as desired.

Comment: SP is a (private) class object, and it is assigned in the constructor

Comment: Also tried with a separate, private, static, readonly object, but the situation is the same.

Comment: Could you provide more context, such as where SendCommand is called from and how multiple threads are being started?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't influence which thread this is run on, as the propertygrid accesses my objects' properties (on the UI thread ofc), which call the SendCommands as side effects. I will probably need to reorganize my code.
Even if I call the SendCommand invocation on a new thread, I still need to block the UI thread in order to wait for the answer from the SendCommand which needs to be returned.

        public int XXX
        {
           get { 
                return SendCommand("SOME DATA HERE");
           }
        }

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, you absolutely should not be calling a method such as this from a property, but especially not from a property getter.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should try/change:

1.Make a separate field, that will be used for locking only

2.Apply the double lock check : [double check locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

Comment: Tried the first one, nothing changes.

Comment: I'm not sure, how I could apply the second suggestion, as I have to carry out the operations in any case, but wait for the current operation to finish first.

Answer (score 0):

SerialPort sp;

```
public byte[] SendCommand(byte[] command)
  {
      //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
      lock (sp)
      {
          Console.Out.WriteLine("ENTER");
          try
          {

              string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(command);

              string request = String.Format("{0}{1}\r", target_UID, base64);

              Console.Out.Write("Sending request... {0}", request);

              sp.Write(request);

              string response;

              do
              {
                  response = sp.ReadLine();
              } while (response.Contains("QQ=="));

              Console.Out.Write("Response is: {0}", response);

              return Convert.FromBase64String(response.Substring(target_UID.Length));
          }

          catch (Exception e)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");
              throw e;
          }
          finally
          {
              Console.Out.WriteLine("EXIT");
          }
      }

  }
```