# How to queue WhenAnyValue subscriber calls containing asynchronous code?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

What is the correct way to prevent subscribers to be called in parallel, before previous call is completed?

I have kind of race condition atm with code like this

```
SomeReactive.WhenAnyValue(o => o.SomeBool).Subscribe(async someBool =>
{
    if(someBool)
    {
        await ...
        Start();
    }
    else
    {
        await ...
        Stop();
    }
});
```

If `SomeBool` changes rapidly, then it can happens that calls will be like this:

```
Start()
Stop()
Stop()
Start()
```

or worse. How can I ensure that it is always

```
Start()
Stop()
Start()
Stop()
```

---

I can put [lock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45769160/1997232) inside or use some kind of queue to ensure order of calls. But I hope there is something existing for situation like this or I rather need to use reactive concept correctly, e.g. creating a new observable or who knows what.

---

Forgot to add mcve. Create new console app, add nugets: `ReactiveUI` and `ReactiveUI.Fody`.

```
class Program
{
    static SomeReactive SomeReactive { get; } = new();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeReactive.WhenAnyValue(o => o.SomeBool).Subscribe(async someBool =>
        {
            if (someBool)
            {
                await Task.Delay((int)(Random.Shared.NextDouble() * 100));
                Console.WriteLine("start");
            }
            else
            {
                await Task.Delay((int)(Random.Shared.NextDouble() * 100));
                Console.WriteLine("stop");
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            SomeReactive.SomeBool = !SomeReactive.SomeBool;
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class SomeReactive : ReactiveObject
{
    [Reactive]
    public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: First you should decide what you want to do - queue changes, skip some changes or maybe do throttling?

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek, from given options I want to queue. Start/Stop pairs should not overlap or skip. I am hoping there is a parameter or certain extension method exist, which can simply block furhter `WhenAnyValue` calls (or accumulate them?) until asynchronous handler is finished.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it - I tried on a small app without success. I would try to go with this question on ReactiveUi Discord.

Comment: I don't know what triggers changes in your app, but maybe another option is to use https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections.html - and try to save a bool value in the collection, and other observable would consume bools one by one. I never tried it, but it looks like a good candidate - classic producer-consumer scenario.

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek, building observable to synchronize calls might be the right way to fix async subscriber order. Though I am unsure how to achieve such "waiting" observables. There is `Observable.FromAsync`, but when googling more for "c# reactiveui async subscriber order" I am rather finding my (this) question =)

Comment: @Sinatr You shouldn't/can't use `async` for the `Subscribe()` method, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006852/how-to-call-back-async-function-from-rx-subscribe.

Comment: @Sinatr What are you trying to do with the async/await call when you actually don't want asynchronous execution anyway? Using async/await means that you go somewhere else to do something else while the other task is running/performing and that is happening here. Please [edit] your question to clarify why you use async/await on that level and not inside a new `Task.Run()` block which you wait for completion (synchronously) (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c).

Comment: @Progman, aye, it's topic with similar issue. As for your question, the subscriber simply calls async methods inside. `Task.Delay` in my example is a work simulation. This should not be illegal and the problem is as per [@StephenCleary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23011084/1997232) is `async void`. I need sort of `SubscribeAsync`  method, which will correctly process and waits for passed async method. As for your suggestion to attempt to run async code synchronously, sorry, been there, done that, will never attempt it again =) And  don't know how using `Task.Run()` would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71846591/1997232) I've made my own `SybscribeAsync` extension method with parameter:

```
public static IDisposable SubscribeAsync<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, Task> func) =>
            source.Select(o => Observable.FromAsync(_ => func(o)))
                .Concat()
                .Subscribe();
```

The method `SubscribeAsync` should be used instead of `Subscribe(async o => ...)`, unless `async void` is not a problem (it could be).

P.S.: naming method `SubscribeSynchronous` like ReactiveMarbles does is the option.

Answer (score 1):

I returned to your question, and I have something promising:

```
SomeReactive.WhenAnyValue(o => o.SomeBool)
    .Select(flag => Observable.Create<Unit>(async _ =>
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Console.WriteLine("Start - select + concat");
        }
        else
        {
            await Task.Delay(300);
            Console.WriteLine("Stop - select + concat");
        }
    }))
    .Concat()
    .Subscribe();
```

`Select` creates a new `Observable` in the pipeline - here, we have a logic. Next, we need to preserve order/not run in parallel, so `Concat` is used. At the end, `Subscribe` is needed.

During my investigation, I also made a less RX code with semaphore.

```
SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new(1);
SomeReactive.WhenAnyValue(o => o.SomeBool).Subscribe(async flag =>
{
    await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

    try
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Console.WriteLine("Start - semaphore");
        }
        else
        {
            await Task.Delay(300);
            Console.WriteLine("Stop - semaphore");
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your first snippet works! But this `Unit` (means `void`) with capturing `flag` stuff looks like a hack to me. The idea to move async code into `Select` is clear. There you convert `bool` into hacky observables with just one item, correct? And then `Concat` is used to wait for those observable to produce item, which is produced after `Console.WriteLine`, right? So `Concat` is awaiting. I also achieve same effect by replacing `)).Concat().Subscribe()` with `).Subscribe()).Subscribe()`, which is more clear to me. Can you comment on this solution?

Comment: The second snippet is a possible solution, which doesn't use reactive. I mentioned it in my question, as well as queue (e.g. with `Task.ContinueWith`), but I was hopping there is a reactive solution, ideally one-liner. Like replacing `Subscribe` with `SubscribeAsync`.

Comment: `Select` transforms value (https://introtorx.com/chapters/transformation-of-sequences). Code that handles bool is void, so result is void (Unit). If you would like to continue pipeline with the flag value, then you can return flag and method will not be void anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Task.Run()` to execute the "inner" part of your `Subscribe()` call with the `await`/`async` keywords, but wait for its completion via `GetAwaiter()` and `GetResult()` *synchronously* inside your `Subscribe()` call (see [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)). The code could look like this:

```
public class Program
{       
    static SomeReactive SomeReactive { get; } = new();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        SomeReactive
            .WhenAnyValue(o => o.SomeBool)
            .Subscribe(someBool => {
                    Task.Run(async ()  =>
                    {
                        if (someBool)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay((int)(Random.Shared.NextDouble() * 1000));
                            Console.WriteLine("start");
                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await Task.Delay((int)(Random.Shared.NextDouble() * 1000));
                            Console.WriteLine("stop");                        
                        }
                    })
                    .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            });

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            SomeReactive.SomeBool = !SomeReactive.SomeBool;
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class SomeReactive : ReactiveObject
{
    [Reactive]
    public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
stop
start
stop
start
stop
start
stop
start
stop
start
stop
```

Comment: Now I see what you mean, thanks. I never thought of using `Task.Run` as a wrapper to run async code, rather oposite, e.g. to run synchronous code in another (non-UI) thread.

Answer (score 0):

If I was trying to do this, I would use SubscribeSynchronus as follows:
Add the nuget package - ReactiveMarbles.Extensions `<PackageReference Include="ReactiveMarbles.Extensions" Version="1.1.12" />` then use as follows:

```cs
    using ReactiveMarbles.Extensions;

    class Program
    {
        static SomeReactive SomeReactive { get; } = new();
    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeReactive
            .WhenAnyValue(o => o.SomeBool)
            .SubscribeSynchronous(async someBool =>
            {
                if (someBool)
                {
                    await Task.Delay((int)(Random.Shared.NextDouble() * 100));
                    Console.WriteLine("start");
                }
                else
                {
                    await Task.Delay((int)(Random.Shared.NextDouble() * 100));
                    Console.WriteLine("stop");
                }
            });
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                SomeReactive.SomeBool = !SomeReactive.SomeBool;
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
    
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    
    class SomeReactive : ReactiveObject
    {
        [Reactive]
        public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
    }
```

Hopefully this works in your situation.

There is also `SyncronizeAsync()` which will add a Sync element to the stream call x.Sync.Dispose() to release the next value and x.Value is the upstream value. This gives more control as to when the next value will be released and allows other functionality to be added in between.

```cs
    using ReactiveMarbles.Extensions;

    class Program
    {
        static SomeReactive SomeReactive { get; } = new();
    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeReactive
            .WhenAnyValue(o => o.SomeBool)
            .SyncronizeAsync()
            .Subscribe(async someBool =>
            {
                if (someBool.Value)
                {
                    await Task.Delay((int)(Random.Shared.NextDouble() * 100));
                    Console.WriteLine("start");
                }
                else
                {
                    await Task.Delay((int)(Random.Shared.NextDouble() * 100));
                    Console.WriteLine("stop");
                }
                
                someBool.Sync.Dispose();
            });
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                SomeReactive.SomeBool = !SomeReactive.SomeBool;
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
    
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    
    class SomeReactive : ReactiveObject
    {
        [Reactive]
        public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You remind me I forgot to add [mcve]. Adding something like `.Synchronize` is what I actually expected to hear! Unfortunately it doesn't help, the output is not synchronized, you can try it yourself.

Comment: The edit looks promising, I am looking [at sources](https://github.com/reactivemarbles/Extensions/blob/df9944878633ef8de76c21bdf9b45507ab50d1c2/src/ReactiveMarbles.Extensions/ReactiveExtensions.cs#L932) now, your second snippet is what `SubscribeSynchronous` is doing under the hood.

Comment: [SynchronizeAsync](https://github.com/reactivemarbles/Extensions/blob/df9944878633ef8de76c21bdf9b45507ab50d1c2/src/ReactiveMarbles.Extensions/ReactiveExtensions.cs#L916) looks terrible to me. It's in principle some weird `lock` with possibly not disposed `Barrier`, another `object` allocated and then `Task.Run()`. Sorry, but no way I am going to try this. =/ But please keep the answer, maybe someone else will use it and upvote, if it works.