# How to avoid stale values when using WhenAnyValue and null propagation?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I need to monitor for changes of nullable `Foo`, including `Foo = null` or changes of any property like `Foo.Bar = 123`.

So I am using this syntax (similar to [recommended](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-any#null-propogation-inside-whenanyvalue)):

```
WhenAnyValue(o => o.Foo, o => o.Foo!.Bar, (foo, bar) => (foo, bar))
```

to subscribe to changes of both `Foo` and `Bar` of my view model:

```
public class VM : ReactiveObject
{
    [Reactive]
    public Foo? Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : ReactiveObject
{
    [Reactive]
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

However, this will run subscriber multiple time with *stale* values. After `Foo = null` subscriber is called with previous value of `Bar` and after `Foo = new()` subscriber is called twice: with previous value of `Bar` and with correct one. This can be demonstrated with following code:

```
var vm = new VM() { Foo = new Foo { Bar = 1 } };

vm.WhenAnyValue(o => o.Foo, o => o.Foo!.Bar, (foo, bar) => (foo, bar))
.Subscribe(o => Console.WriteLine($"{o.foo?.GetHashCode()} {o.bar}"));

vm.Foo = null; // #1

vm.Foo = new Foo { Bar = 2 }; // #2
```

The output looks like this:

```
58225482 1
 1                   << stale Bar
32347029 1           << stale Bar
32347029 2           << extra call
```

Instead I want something like this:

```
58225482 1
 0
32347029 2
```

In other words, I don't want to have *stale* values and extra subscriber call if possible.

The `Foo == null` check inside subscriber will solve #1. But maybe there is a different rx solution to such a problem? Or is moving null check outside of subscriber somehow is also ok?

As for #2, I have only idea of workaround with storing previous value of `Foo` and ignore first call if previous value was `null`. Again, it's a procedural way of programming. How this should be done in rx world of programming?

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate the problem more clearly I have increased the number  `Foo` properties:

```
public class Foo : ReactiveObject
{
    [Reactive]
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    [Reactive]
    public int Baz { get; set; }
    [Reactive]
    public int Qux { get; set; }
}
```

Then the output of

```
var vm = new VM();

vm.WhenAnyValue(o => o.Foo, o => o.Foo!.Bar, o => o.Foo!.Baz, o => o.Foo!.Qux,
    (foo, bar, baz, qux) => (foo, bar, baz, qux)).Subscribe(o =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{o.foo?.GetHashCode()} {o.bar} {o.baz} {o.qux}");
});

vm.Foo = new();
vm.Foo = null;
vm.Foo = new Foo { Bar = 1, Baz = 2, Qux = 3 };
vm.Foo = null;
vm.Foo = new();
```

will contain lots of stale states:

```
30631159 0 0 0
 0 0 0
56680499 0 0 0
56680499 1 0 0
56680499 1 2 0
56680499 1 2 3
 1 2 3
6444509 1 2 3
6444509 0 2 3
6444509 0 0 3
6444509 0 0 0
```

---

Here is a fixed version of subscriber:

```
{
    // discard stale state
    if (o.foo != null && (o.bar != o.foo.Bar || o.baz != o.foo.Baz || o.qux != o.foo.Qux))
        return;

    // Console.WriteLine($"{o.foo?.GetHashCode()} {o.bar} {o.baz} {o.qux}");
    // use actual null propagated values!
    Console.WriteLine($"{o.foo?.GetHashCode()} {o.foo?.Bar} {o.foo?.Baz} {o.foo?.Qux}");
}
```

Now the output is as expected, one line per change:

```
30631159 0 0 0

56680499 1 2 3

6444509 0 0 0
```

In other words:

- the subscriber to null propagation will always require a check to discard stale states;
- <s>null propagated values should not be used inside subscriber, their purpose is  to detect their individual changes, e.g. when `vm.Foo.Bar = 123;`</s>

EDIT: The second statement is incorrect, with discard there is no stale state anymore and values are correct, unless subscriber takes too long to finish, but that's [another story](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77489039/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

`.WhenAnyValue` reacts on **any** observable change, and it do code by gathering all values that are observed.

If you are interested in only `Bar`, `Baz`, `Qux`, then you can omit `Foo`, and you will get less notifications:

```
vm.WhenAnyValue(o => o.Foo!.Bar, o => o.Foo!.Baz, o => o.Foo!.Qux,
        (bar, baz, qux) => (bar, baz, qux))
    .Subscribe(o =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{o.bar} {o.baz} {o.qux}");
});

// output
0 0 0
1 0 0
1 2 0
1 2 3
0 2 3
0 0 3
0 0 0
```

Based on your expected output it looks that you want to track only a `Foo` change:

```
vm.WhenAnyValue(o => o.Foo)
    .Where(o => o != null)
    .Subscribe(o => Console.WriteLine($"{o.Bar} {o.Baz} {o.Qux}"));

// output
0 0 0
1 2 3
0 0 0
```

Comment: I am using null propagation in first place only because I need to react on `null` as well. I should've told that or demonstrated in my mcve, sorry. And the stale state is exclusive to solution proposed by reactiveUI team.  Also I need to monitor for individual property changes, e.g. `Bar`. Your second snippet is not catching such changes.