# WhenAnyValue filtering

Tags: c#, reactiveui

How can I filter `WhenAnyValue` values, similar to use of `.When()` in LINQ?

---

The story: I am performing filtering inside the subscriber (full code is in my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77781052/1997232)):

```
vm.WhenAnyValue(o => o.Foo, o => o.Foo!.Bar, o => o.Foo!.Baz, o => o.Foo!.Qux,
    (foo, bar, baz, qux) => (foo, bar, baz, qux)).Subscribe(o =>
{
    if (o.foo != null && (o.bar != o.foo.Bar || o.baz != o.foo.Baz || o.qux != o.foo.Qux))
        return;
      
    Console.WriteLine($"{o.foo?.GetHashCode()} {o.foo?.Bar} {o.foo?.Baz} {o.foo?.Qux}");
});
```

This works, but I'd like to move `if` check outside of subscriber and do not pass `bar`, `baz` and `qux` into subscriber, because they are unsafe to use (due to null propagation they may contain stale values and I want to force using of `foo` to reach their values).