# .NET Event Handling When an Event Is Fired While Another Event Handler is Already Running

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, eventhandler

There is an issue that makes me curious about for quite some time.
Assume this scenario:
You created a program in C#, which has some classes inwhich you defined some events,
and other classes consume those events - they implement event handler methods for them.

My question:
What are the CLR's "rules" for running the event handler(s), for cases where events happen simultaneously?

If one event handler is running, and another event was raised now, will the CLR let the current event handler finish, and then just go to the next event handler? (the "second" event might be a second raise of the same event, or a different event)
Or is there a case where the CLR pauses the current event handler due to an event that came in the middle, then runs the second event handler, and then resumes back to the middle of the first event handler that was left?

Any info or article that makes an order in this, will be greatly appreciated.

BTW:
For this question, please assume 2 possible situations:
1) The classes with the events and event handlers are not Controls
   (simple classes that you write, that inherit type object and not type Control)
2) The classes with the events and event handlers are inheriting class Control (Windows Forms)

I mention this because maybe the behavior/rules are different between the two.

Also, I would be grateful if you can relate to following things, that might affect the answers to these 2 questions:
- **Application.DoEvents()** method
- **Timer**s
- any other class/method like this that might give different results beyond the simple ones that we might think of in the "normal" case..

Thank you

Comment: If it is single threaded they can't "happen simultaneously", and if it is multithreaded, then both will happen simultaneously.

Comment: Unexpected reentry is a common problem with event handlers in applications with event loops like UI applications. I suppose this would be perceived as a "pause" of the current method, however it is not controlled by any CLR policy. It is the design of the application's event loop that causes this.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thank you, can you please elaborate more on this, or refer to a place I can learn more about it? (like where it can happen, what can be done to prevent it in cases we want to prevent, what can be done to enable it, in places where we actually want it to happen, and so)

Comment: @spaceman This [answer by Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13985497/517852) illustrates the scenario nicely with a toy example that is a simplified version of the message loop that runs in a normal UI application. Note that `Application.DoEvents` is exactly the sort of method "which pumps a message loop" that he warns about.

Answer (score -1):

This has *nothing* to do with the CLR or the language.  It's purely based on the specific implementation of the class defining the method.  It can be written such that it fires of the event while handlers for a previous invocation are still running, or it could not.  If you're dealing with a winforms program then most object firing events are firing them in the UI thread, so since there is only one thread that can be firing the events it can't ever fire them while other handlers are still running, but there are other objects that aren't forcing their usage to a single thread and as such can fire an event while handlers for a previous invocation are still running.

So all you can really do is look at the documentation/source code or do some experimental tests to see what any particular class does, or be safe and assume the worst case.  There is no general case answer.